# Upgrading to RSpec 2: errors replaced with have(n).errors_on? Need a work-around

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Here is some sample tests from my rspec 1.x code:

```
[:email, :contact_type_id].each do |attr|
  it "requires #{attr}" do
    e = EmailAddress.new
    e.should_not be_valid
    # i don't care how many errors there are,
    # just that there were errors for this attr.
    e.errors(attr).should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

RSpec 2.6.x is forcing me to do this:

```
[:email, :contact_type_id].each do |attr|
  it "requires #{attr}" do
    e = EmailAddress.new
    e.should_not be_valid
    # have expects that I pass a number here :(
    e.should have(n).error_on(attr)
  end
end
```

I don't care HOW many errors there are, just that errors showed up when trying to validate the model. It would be cool if I could do something like:

```
e.should have.errors_on(attr)
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
e.should have_at_least(1).error_on(attr)
```